# angularJS : validation pattern should allow ? but should not save to server

Tags: regex, html, angularjs, validation

Plz check example where i need to show "??" into textbox initially.

but those "??" should not save to the server means it should save data validated by regEx.

For that i am assigning "??" initially its fire the validation however

"??" not showing to the textbox.

So what is work around for that ?

Below is the HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
<input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" required>
<span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/></form></div>
```

Below is the Javascript

```
function formCtrl($scope){
$scope.price= "??";
$scope.onSubmit = function(){
    alert("form submitted");
}}
```

Plz check on JsFiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ar6eb/)

-Thanks,

Yogesh

Comment: Why not use `placeholder="??"` instead of giving it invalid value?

Comment: @user3249448 Take a look at my answer

Comment: Thanks for reply...                                           Actually price is coming from ICR once the document read. If ICR not able to read price from document then it returns me "????" which i am not able to show in textbox due to regEX. Price will dynamically get bind to textbox using "ng-model" and also i need to support IE8 where placeholders have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems input doesn't show up until it matches the regex

So try this,

Html file,

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit(price)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="price" required  />
   <span ng-hide="validater">Not a valid number!</span><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Js file,

```
function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.price= "??";
       $scope.onSubmit = function(price){
       $scope.validater= new RegExp("^\[0-9]{1,7}$").test(price);

        //alert("validater "+ $scope.validater);

        if(!$scope.validater){
              $scope.price= "??";
        }else{
           alert("form submitted");

        }

        return  $scope.validater;       

    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem :)

Here is the working demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfNEF/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()"> 

<input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" placeholder="Enter a number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" required>

<span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>

<input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" value="submit"/></form></div>
```

And in your JS

```
function formCtrl($scope){
$scope.price= "-1";
$scope.onSubmit = function(){
    alert("form submitted");
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ar6eb/2/)**

[image]

**html**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" placeholder="??" required >
    <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

**script**

```
function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.price= "";
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
        alert("form submitted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...                                           Actually price is coming from ICR once the document read. If ICR not able to read price then it returns me "????" which i am not able to show in textbox due to regEX. Price will dynamically get bind to textbox using "ng-model" and also i need to support IE8 where placeholders have an issue.